# Text seems a bit blurry on a backdrop blur (html/css)

Tags: html, css

I'm currently facing a slight problem with text on top of a 'glass-morphism' effect that is achieved by the `backdrop-filter: blur()` property. In some cases, the text on top of the div with the glass effect seems a bit blurred or something. This seems to happen when the text jumps to the next line, due to the variable width.

Side-by-side comparisons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKuMm.jpg.

As you can see, the difference between the viewport width can be as small as 1 pixel. Removing the backdrop-filter fixes the issue, but I'd like to keep it if it's possible. I've tested this in Chrome and Edge (and Internet Explorer, but that doesn't support the backdrop-filter property). Both came out the same.

This is the code for the 'glass' div:

```css
.glassback {
   height: auto;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
   box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
   backdrop-filter: blur( 4px );
   -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px );
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 25px;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 glassback">
    <h3 class="landingpage">FIND YOUR NEW HOME TODAY.</h3>
    <br>
    <p class="landingpage">We offer a wide variety of apartments and studios in cities like <b>Eindhoven</b>, <b>Tilburg</b> and <b>Arnhem</b>.</p>
    <p class="landingpage">Now the real question is:<br>where do <b>you</b> want to live?</p>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="row">                       
            <div class="col-10">
                <select name="cityselection" id="cityselection" class="form-control overflow">
                    <option class="overflow" value="all" selected>Eindhoven, Tilburg, Arnhem, &#39;s-Hertogenbosch...</option>
                    <option value="Eindhoven">Eindhoven</option>
                    <option value="Tilburg">Tilburg</option>
                    <option value="Arnhem">Arnhem</option>
                    <option value="sHertogenbosch">&#39;s-Hertogenbosch</option>
                    <option value="Amersfoort">Amersfoort</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 searchbutton">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>   
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any clue? If you need more info, just ask! :)

Comment: please share the full css code

Comment: I'm also having this problem. have you found a solution

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly due to the browser engine, and the blurry fonts effect can vary depending of your `browser`, `div` size, and even your browser `render interpretation`. FYI, this behavior also affects `div` drawings (like a circle having a border radius `100%`). Edges can be blurry also in this case.

In all this mess you have a proper workaround: don't apply the `backdrop-filter` to the div that contains your text, but create a separate `absolute` div that has the effect, and place it below your text or content. Here is the fix of your code:

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 glassback">
    <div class="effect"></div>
    <h3 class="landingpage">FIND YOUR NEW HOME TODAY.</h3>
    <br>
    <p class="landingpage">We offer a wide variety of apartments and studios in cities like <b>Eindhoven</b>, <b>Tilburg</b> and <b>Arnhem</b>.</p>
    <p class="landingpage">Now the real question is:<br>where do <b>you</b> want to live?</p>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="row">                       
            <div class="col-10">
                <select name="cityselection" id="cityselection" class="form-control overflow">
                    <option class="overflow" value="all" selected>Eindhoven, Tilburg, Arnhem, &#39;s-Hertogenbosch...</option>
                    <option value="Eindhoven">Eindhoven</option>
                    <option value="Tilburg">Tilburg</option>
                    <option value="Arnhem">Arnhem</option>
                    <option value="sHertogenbosch">&#39;s-Hertogenbosch</option>
                    <option value="Amersfoort">Amersfoort</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 searchbutton">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>   
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.glassback {
    height: auto;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    position: relative;
}
.effect {
    backdrop-filter: blur( 4px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4px );
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

And a snippet with a concret example:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/S57AcCZ.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.effect {
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px) saturate(100%);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px) saturate(100%);
  background-color: rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="effect"></div>
  <div class="content">
    here is my sharp text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem causing the blurry text was having the `transform` property on the element with the `backdrop-filter` property. In my case, it was simple enough to relegate the job being performed by `transform` to some other properties to achieve the same effect, allowing me to use the filter without having blurry text.

Of course, it may not be possible for all users to remove the `transform` property without hassle but I figured thought I'd share a possible solution.