# Does applying `backdrop-filter` property reduces text sharpness in HTML?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, text, blur

This is driving me crazy, I seem to not be able to apply a `backdrop-filter: blur` effect on my card element without keeping the text inside it just as sharp as it normally should be.
This issue was previously discussed here:
[Text seems a bit blurry on a backdrop blur (html/css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65788900/text-seems-a-bit-blurry-on-a-backdrop-blur-html-css)

but I wonder if there is a "proper way" to fix/get around this without recurring to absolute positioning and creating additional elements, since I also have some translate animations on the element and it's just bloated like that...

> comments are some attempts I read online for relative issues...
> the `children` element is only text...

[image: without backdrop-filter text is fine]

[image: with backdrop-filter (even if it is "blur(0px)" ) text is less sharp]

[image: this is the jsx html with some other tailwindcss class]

> here is the two text screenshotted and edited next to each other
> (over the white line is the text with `backdrop-filter: blur(0px)` and under it is the text without it:
> [image: text difference]

I tried some other css properties to add with backdrop-filter and was gonna try to fill the space with 0 opacity text and `position: absolute` another sibling text into it but refused to do it when it came down to tracking the animated div repeatedly.

I was expecting the text to not be influenced by the property.

## How to reproduce

1. Create a brand new react project with `npm create vite@latest` -> `typescript + swc`
2. Go into the `App.tsx` file in the `src` folder
3. Let's take the last `<p>` tag as a sample, add a `card-glass` css class (and remove the default `read-the-docs` class if you prefer) and put whatever text you want in it
4. Go into the `App.css` file and add the `card-glass` css class:

```css
.card-glass {
  background-color: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff00, #ffffff88);
  /* backdrop-filter: blur(0px); */
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

now you can toggle the commented `backdrop-filter` property to see the text being "antialiased" and smoothed when the property is on, even with `0px` as value

Comment: Please add a relevant snippet so we can see the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added an "how to reproduce" section, but I tried to check it on other machines and seems like it's something to do on how I setted up mine... (I'm guessing it may be some readability options on Windows 10 which I'm on, or maybe some accessibility stuff, although I don't have any particular need for those I may have changed something here and there years ago) I'll keep this updated as I discover some stuff